# Angular2 - KarmaJS - unit Tests no executed automatically on npm test

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm using KarmaJS and JasmineJS for unit testing on Angular2.
When I run "npm test" the browser opened automatically, however the tests not executed automatically.

[image: npm test]

If I change any file all the tests will be executed in the project.

[image: success]

Here my "**karma.conf.js**"

[image]

Here my "**test.ts**" file that I refer in "karma.conf.js"

[image: test.ts]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was excluding all *.spec.ts files in tsconfig.json.

> > "exclude": [
> >         "node_modules",
> >         "wwwroot",
> >         "typings/browser",
> >         "typings/main",
> >         "typings/browser.d.ts",
> >         "typings/main.d.ts",
> >         "dist",
> >         **"**/*.spec.ts"** ...
>
> It has to be like :
>
> "exclude": [
>       "node_modules",
>       "wwwroot",
>       "typings/browser",
>       "typings/main",
>       "typings/browser.d.ts",
>       "typings/main.d.ts",
>       "dist" ], "files": [
>       "test.ts" ], "include": [
>       "**/*.spec.ts",
>       "***/.d.ts" ]...